# Values are not displaying on TextView

Tags: android

I have a couple issues with a math program im currently working on im trying to make a delete button so the user can remove any mistake made and also i want to append("0") but it does nothing when i press both buttons. When i append values from 1-9 it displays it but wierdly it does nothing when pressing delete and one. answer is a TextView. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
        case R.id.delete:
            answer.append("");
            break;
        case R.id.zero:
            answer.append("0");
            break;
```

Comment: I assume these delete and zero values are set as int's when you are trying to use them? More code would help us.

Comment: Obviously appending an empty string will lead to no visible change.  Perhaps you're wanting to .setText() ?  Your "0" case is fine -- but you complain about your "1" case, not shown, in the text of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If answer is a TextView, then you should do something like this to append a 0:

answer.setText(answer.getText().toString()+0);

Comment: [TextView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: It *is* appending a zero.  Both the original code and your code are correct -- which is why your code doesn't correct anything.

Comment: I just wanted to help... And which is the problem with the original code not working well? You downvoted me but you have no contributed to a right answer so far, as what you say is trivial...

Comment: The OP doesn't yet have an answerable question.  Would you not downvote someone who, to "My house just burned down! It's because I wrote `a += 5` !", responds with "If you want to add 5 to an int variable, you need to do `a++; a++; a++; a++; a++;`, or else `a = a + 5`" ?